# Pandas internal algorithm for join and groupby?

Tags: pandas, database, sorting, join, group-by

After spending hours on the web and also having some reviews on Pandas source code, I could not find the general algorithm that Pandas uses for the execution of its join, merge, and groupby APIs. In other words, does Pandas use a hash-based or sort-merge-based join in its merge/join APIs? What about the groupby? Does it take the hash-based or sort-based approach?

These are the related source code pages: [merge](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.0/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py)| [groupby](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.0/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py)